# How to write content within tags of a html element JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I am thinking something similar to how you in php can just run a function within a html element and that way get it to echo something in the html element.
Is there a way to choose a specific place for javascript to write with for example .innerHTML or .createTextNode?

What I wanna do is to add contenteditable="true" within a html element onclick of another button.

The reason I wanna do this is because I have a paragraph that should become editable only after onclick of a button.

I apologize that I haven't put in any code for an example, but I don't really think that is needed, as it would only be a paragraph and a button, as I don't know how the javascript should be written.

Comment: Yes - using plain js just modify element's innerHtml or using jquery you can modify it using .html function.

Comment: @Daniel Alsaker, Your question needs formatting, it's very difficult to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a simple js onclick event you can do this

```
onclick="document.getElementById('p').setAttribute('contenteditable', true);"
```

here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vert3x/4e6rumg4/) for this.

Comment: Thank you! That's just what I needed. Never used setAttribute before

Answer (score 0):

see with http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2 & https://api.jquery.com/click/

for exemple:

```
$( "#target" ).click(function() {
  $("#yourId").attr("contenteditable", true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean something like this:

HTML

```
<textarea id="c" readonly>Some data</textarea>
<button id="a">
Make editable
</button>
```

Javascript (with jQuery)

```
$("#a").on('click', function() {
    $("#c").attr('readonly', false);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
  $("#myButton").click(function() {
    $("#myDiv").prop("contenteditable", true);
  });
});
```

```css
#myDiv{
 height:300px;
 width:300px;
  background:yellow;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="myDiv"></div>
<button id="myButton">Enable content Editable</button>
```